# Update multiple lines, with many different values in 1 oracle procedure

Tags: oracle

example, i need update 3 rows. I'm doing is running UPDATE Statement 3 time to update each row:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'a' where col2 = '1';
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'b' where col2 = '2';
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'c' where col2 = '3';
```

So is there a way to make it faster, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three `update`s are a very reasonable approach.  You could also do:

```
update table
    set col1 = (case when col2 = 1 then 'a'
                     when col2 = 2 then 'b'
                     when col2 = 3 then 'c'
                     else col1
                end)
    where col2 in (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: With the `where` clause, the `else` part of the `case` expression is not necessary (it doesn't hurt, but it's just not needed).

Comment: i want to using sp so i can call from my apps, can you suggest me for a sp with parameter